# it is prompted that errors exist in required project, but no error is displayed in the taskbar below

Tags: anylogic

As shown in the image below, whenever I run my model, it always tells me that there is an error exists in my model.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCXkg.png)

But when I turn to the "Problems" window at the bottom of my workspace, it doesn't show any exceptions, and the model also works normally.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gCoF.png)

I want to know how can I deal with the problem, and is there an error in my model, what may cause such a  problem?

Comment: Would you mind posting the code (or a minimum reproducable example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These can happen rarely, typically it is not a problem. Try any of these options:

- Close the model, then close AnyLogic, then restart and reopen
- Delete your Workspace folder (C:/Users/username/.AnyLogicProfessional/Workspace8.8), then restart AnyLogic
- Reinstall AnyLogic

Likely the 2nd will help, but try them all